# How to lazy load relations for all collections at once in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am developing an application to predict scores of football matches. In the application I update the UI live when the user predicts the scores of match. This is to show the % of people who predicted home team win, draw or away team win. To improve the performance, I cache some of the data queried, but there is one relation that I need to lazy load every time the user changes the prediction.

Here is part of my code.

```
public function getGroupsProperty()
{
    $groups = Cache::remember('groups', '3600', function () {
        return Group::whereId(1)->with('matches')->get();
    });

    foreach($groups as $group) {
        foreach($group->matches as $match) {
            // comment 1
            $predictions = $match->predictions->whereNotNull('team_a_score')->whereNotNull('team_b_score');
            foreach($predictions as $prediction) {
                // code to show prediction chart for the match
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the above code you can see that I am eager loading the `matches` for the `group`. Later on in the line after `// comment 1` I am loading the predictions for each match. This makes too many calls to database as there are more than 50 matches.

I am wondering if there is a way, where I can lazy load the `predictions` relation for all the `matches` at once. This will reduce the query count to just 1.

Is this possible in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it like below and it is working now.

```
public function getGroupsProperty()
{
    $groups = Cache::remember('groups', '3600', function () {
        return Group::whereId(1)->with('matches')->get();
    });

    foreach($groups as $group) {
        // lazy load predictions here...
        $group->matches->load('predictions');
        foreach($group->matches as $match) {  
            $predictions = $match->predictions->whereNotNull('team_a_score')->whereNotNull('team_b_score');
            foreach($predictions as $prediction) {
                // code to show prediction chart for the match
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so, if you read the documentation, you can do [`with('matches.predictions')`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading) and that will Eager Load (not [`Lazy Load`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)) the models.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. As I mentioned, I cache the matches of the group. if I cache predictions with the matches, I will not get the most recent predictions of all the users as one user update their prediction. As many users will be predicting the scores at the same time, I need the real time prediction details in order to update the prediction percentage chart. Hence I want to lazy load predictions for all the matches at once (rather than separate 50+ queries) as a user predicts the score. The function `getGroupsProperty` will be called each time a user updates the prediction.